# "Lost" 30% of records after partitioning

Tags: mysql, partitioning

I've got a MYISAM table of 90 million records over 18GB of data, and tests suggest it's a candidate for partitioning.

Original schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `email_tracker` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `hash` varchar(65) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `userId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `dateSent` datetime NOT NULL,
  `dateViewed` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `userId` (`userId`),
  KEY `dateSent` (`dateSent`),
  KEY `dateViewed` (`dateViewed`),
  KEY `hash` (`hash`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci 1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

I've previously partitioned the table on a test server with "ALTER TABLE email_tracker PARTITION BY HASH..." and run typical queries against it, and there were no problems with the queries. To avoid locking the table on the production DB, I'm testing again on the test server using this approach as we can afford to lose some tracking data while this runs:

```
RENAME TABLE email_tracker TO email_tracker_orig; CREATE TABLE email_tracker LIKE email_tracker_orig;
CREATE TABLE email_tracker_part LIKE email_tracker_orig;
ALTER TABLE email_tracker_part DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD PRIMARY KEY (id, userId);
ALTER TABLE email_tracker_part PARTITION BY HASH (id + userId) partitions 30;
INSERT INTO email_tracker_part (SELECT * FROM email_tracker_orig);
```

The _orig table has 90,795,103 records. After the query, the _part table only has 68,282,298. And I have no idea why that might be. Any ideas?

```
mysql> select count(*) from email_tracker_orig;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
| 90795103 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select count(*) from email_tracker_part;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
| 68274818 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

(On subsequent tests, the _part table contains slightly different numbers of records which is weirder still)

Edit #1: Just realised that half of the partition table are empty due to auto-increment-increment = 2 for replication, so going to repartition BY KEY (userId) and see how that works out.

Edit #2 - Still the same after re-partitioning so trying to identify missing rows to establish a pattern.

Comment: Try to find few records that are lost and see what they have in common/different from the rows that were copied to the other table.

Comment: @zerkms - makes sense. However, I've realised that half of the partition tables are empty as auto-increment-increment = 2 for replication, so I'm going to partition differently first and see what happens

Comment: Are you determining the number of rows by select (`select count(*) from email_tracker_orig`) or from the values in `information_schema.TABLES`?

Comment: @RayBaxter - SELECT COUNT(*) which I've always relied on with MYISAM, and phpMyAdmin is giving the same number of rows (not sure what query is used there). Just re-partitioning so will confirm using information_schema next

Comment: You can skip the query of `information_schema` as it is often inaccurate, but it changes over time consistent with your results after the second iteration.

Comment: @RayBaxter - after re-partitioning, both SELECT COUNT(*) and  SELECT table_name, TABLE_ROWS FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '{db_name}' are still inconsistent.

Comment: auto_increment_increment has nothing to do with the record count.

Comment: information_schema is accurate for MyISAM, not for InnoDB.

Comment: I would be very interested to find out what test showed that Hashing would make queries perform better.  In my experience, `BY HASH` does not increase performance for _any_ use case.

Comment: @RickJames - yes, auto_increment_increment = 2 has nothing to do with the record count. But it does mean that ids for this table are % 2. So odd numbered ids don't exist, and partitions for odd numbered ids are empty. So it's inefficient having 30 partitions if 15 are empty.

Comment: @RickJames - I didn't say that queries performed better. I said "there were no problems with the queries" in that some frequently-called queries performed exactly the same as before partitioning, and some less-frequent ones were slower in a way that is acceptable.

Comment: If performance was not better, why use `BY HASH`?

Comment: @RickJames - edited to reflect that re-partitioning was done BY KEY (userId)

Comment: I don't have an answer to the missing rows; instead I am trying to talk you out of partitioning.

Comment: @RickJames - I understand that you're questioning the reasoning behind wanting to partition. The absolute main benefit we're after here is better recoverability options - AIUI, checking and repairing individual dirty partitions is easier than having to check an entire table, especially with the number of records involved here. But I am looking again at what I'm doing here to ensure we get that benefit, and don't just end up with 30 dirty partitions that all need checking in the event of a crash.

Comment: @RickJames - and the solution is some refactoring to ensure all queries use WHERE date_sent as the main index, so I can partition on RANGE date_sent which seems to be a better solution all round. Thanks for prodding me to look closer at this :)

Comment: If all the queries say `WHERE (date_sent BETWEEN '..' AND '..') AND (some-other-range)` then you effectively need a 2-dimensional index.  Yes, this would be a good use case for `PARTITION BY RANGE(TO_DAYS(date_sent))`.  [More tips](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the INSERT query merely terminated prematurely - exactly 40 mins in this case. Just re-running this for the missing records is doing the trick:

```
INSERT INTO email_tracker_part (SELECT * FROM email_tracker_orig WHERE id > 148893974);
```

There's nothing in the my.cnf that suggests a timeout of 40 mins, and I've been running longer queries than this on this test server, but I have my solution so I'll close this even though the underlying reason remains unclear to me.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of your requirements, but the mysql [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-hash.html) states that "the use of hashing expressions involving multiple columns is not particularly recommended." I would recommend that you just partition by `id`. Partitioning by `id + userId` doesn't give any obviously better distribution of your elements across the partitions.

Comment: As mentioned, I realised after the first pass that partitioning by id was no appropriate as this DB is part of a master-master replication so auto-increment-increment is set to 2. Hence, half the partition tables are empty. Now re-partitioned on userId.

Comment: Partition pruning is impossible unless all the columns of the partition key are explicitly specified in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @RickJames - pruning will not be required in this case